Why .NET generates defensive copies for readonly structs in Jitted methods
I'm trying to understand why .NET generates defensive copies for readonly structs. Defensive copy prevents data from being modified. But, if struct is marked as readonly then it is impossible to modify the struct. However, I see that defensive copies are created in various scenarios.
For example, for Core CLR 8.0.824.36612 on x86 on SharpLab.IO example I see creation of defensive copy unless I specify in modifier in M1 parameter.
public readonly struct Foo
{ 
    public readonly int i1; 
    public readonly int i2; 
    public readonly int i3; 
    public readonly int i4;
    public readonly int i5;
    public readonly int i6;
    public readonly int i7;
}

public class C 
{
    public static int M(Foo foo) 
    {
        var a = M1(foo);
        return a + 1;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static int M1(Foo f) 
    {
       return f.i1 + 1;
    }
}

And copy is created
C.M(Foo)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: vzeroupper
    L0006: sub esp, 0x1c
    L0009: vmovdqu xmm0, [ebp+8]
    L000e: vmovdqu [esp], xmm0
    L0013: vmovq xmm0, [ebp+0x18]
    L0018: vmovq [esp+0x10], xmm0
    L001e: mov eax, [ebp+0x20]
    L0021: mov [esp+0x18], eax
    L0025: call dword ptr [0x322ac7b4]
    L002b: inc eax
    L002c: pop ebp
    L002d: ret 0x1c

My question, is there any reason to generate defensive copy in that scenario and why not just pass stack pointer to M1 method?

" But, if struct is marked as readonly then it is impossible to modify the struct" - Nothing is impossible inside a computer.

I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact your struct Foo is huge, so the CLR might be using a different set of rules compared to ideal-sized structs (16 bytes or smaller)

I don't believe what you are seeing is, strictly speaking, a defensive copy. When you declare a method as public static int M1(Foo f) you are passing the struct Foo f by value which is an explicit copy.  A defensive copy occurs when you are passing a struct by reference and it gets copied any, or when calling a mutable method on a readonly value and a copy gets made, then the method is called on the copy.

See e.g. Avoiding struct and readonly reference performance pitfalls with ErrorProne.NET or When gets a record struct copied automatically?.

See also Method Parameters: By default, arguments in C# are passed to functions by value. That means a copy of the variable is passed to the method. For value (struct) types, a copy of the value is passed to the method...  So as per language requirement Foo will get coped when passed by value.

So does When gets a record struct copied automatically? answer your question sufficiently to mark it as a duplicate?  Or does Are structs 'pass-by-value'??  Or do you need some more specific answer?

@dbc I know that there are many recomendations how to avoid Defensive Copies, and in many cases I see that on assembler level it actually performs that optimization even if struct doesn't have readonly modifier and there are no hints in parameters. So to make that optimization, compiler should know that method it calls doesn't mutate the struct. I don't understand why even to create copy in first place when dealing with readonly structs, and to enforce this optimization for readonly structs by default. Maybe there is downside in jitting time or something, but it would answer my question.

@Irdis when you do public static int M1(Foo f) you are explicitly telling the compiler that the public static method M1() has to be passed a copy of Foo.  Similarly when you do public static int M1(Foo f) you are explicitly telling the compiler that the public static method M1() should be passed a copy of Foo.  Is that what you are seeing in the IL?  Or are there extra, additional copes getting made and I'm not understanding the IL correctly?

@dbc yes, all right.  but I also expect to see elimination of Defensive Copy optimization to take place. When I switch to x64 compiler it actualy performs that optimization for me, and I don't see allocation and coping data on M stackframe. I have been experimenting for a while with different setups. But in the end it feels like sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't.

@Irdis well if I remove [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] on sharplab I get nearly identical IL (noinlining is applied to M1) but different and much simpler JIT Asm: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwDoBKBXAdsASygFN0BhAeygAcCAbYgJwGUmA3AgY2IgG4BYAFBC4AZiSNiYACYVcdAJ5IIwRtk7AkAMQoUhAbyRCkJlOMky5ipAXw3UvI4NNmJU2fKW3NBAEyPjUzE3S08bOwJRAOcg83crLwiAFgEYk2CLD2tvGwBWVJcM+LCcggA2AtiQrMSfAHZUgF8RcThfJDIkfUD01tQy8M0AWQAKHQokADNdAEounpckNjBGJDAkAF4kIdQR6YoZysWUOrWkAGokBwXm4TSkAHoHgG0h4mAACwppAEkaOhGb0+3z+1DoAHlqIQ5BB0AA5Cg/eS2WwAcxmAF0FsE0AMcjsxropnNuvcgqdJugCKgLlcjkhbo0gA===

@dbc you need to create long enough method ) https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwDoBKBXAdsASygFN0BhAeygAcCAbYgJwGUmA3AgY2IgG4BYAFBC4AZiSNiYACYVcdAJ5IIwRtk7AkAMQoUhAbyRCkJlOMky5ipAXw3UvI4NNmJU2fKW3NBAEyPjUzE3S08bOwJRAOcg83crLwiAFgEYk2CLD2tvGwBWVJcM+LCcggA2AtiQrMSfAHZUgF8RcThfJDIkfUD01tQy8M0AWQAKHQokADNdAEounpckNjBGJDAkAF4kIdQR6YoZysWUOrWkAGokBwXm4TSkAHoHgG0h4mAACwppAEkaOhGb0+3z+1DoAHlqIQ5BB0AA5Cg/eS2WwAcxmAF0FsE0AMcjsxropnNuvcXARJkg9ugCKgkAA+K4zQxwU4OJC3Y4mClUyY09qM1DMk5XRycrk86mRBlMllssULcmUqXiQXC1mijmK9KnPm0i6im5CRpAA

It is not a defensive copy, you're seeing the side-effect of the x86 calling convention.  Large structs that don't fit in the CPU registers are passed by reference.  It isn't specific to  C#, example

@HansPassant it is a deffensive copy watch how on x86 struct is passed without coping struct on M frame if I add in hint. https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwDoBKBXAdsASygFN0BhAeygAcCAbYgJwGUmA3AgY2IgG4BYAFBC4AZiSNiYACYVcdAJ5IIwRtk7AkAMQoUhAbyRCkJlOMky5ipAXw3UvI4NNmJU2fKW3NBAEyPjUzE3S08bOwJRAOcg83crLwiAFgEYk2CLD2tvGwBWVJcM+LCcggA2AtiQrMSfAHZUgF8RcThfJDIkfUD01tQy8M0AWQAKHQokADNdABpBpAAjAEounpckNjBGJDAkAF4kIdQR6Yo55cr1lDqdpABqJAc15uE0pABtIeJgAAsKaQAkjQ6CMvr9/kDqHQAPLUQhyCDoAByFAB8lstgA5ksALprYJoAY5I4jWzaXRTOY5ZarN5BG6TdAEVD3KZMm4PBaXJAvRpAA=

... because, by definition, structs are passed by value; and anything else is an "out", "ref" or a kludge. (IMO) "It's in its nature".

in is not a hint. It's a modifier similar to out and ref which causes the argument to be passed by reference rather than by value (these modifiers differ for purposes of definite assignment and initialization). So when you change the parameter to in, the compiler takes the address of the readonly foo and passes the address to M1.

@AntonTykhyy and why it cannot do the same when there is no in modifier, the sameway how it did for x64 version.

@AntonTykhyy I mean in x64 I don't see any copy and it does exacty what you described and there is no in modifier. Why it cannot do the same in x86 https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABABgAJiBGAOgCUBXAOwwEt8YaBhCfAB1YAbGFADKIgG6swMXAG4AsAChlxAMzlY2ACYQmggJ7lcGKAzAZyAMQgRlAb3LLyLyhq279R1i3Ksqck5Krm6aMDp6hn6+rABMgc6u6mERXtGWrGoJwUnu4Z5RPhkoijkuyR6R3jEArKUhFflV6X5I9bkpBdUZAOylAL6qGsSx5Fzk9onlw1RILQCyABQ2EOQAZrYAlBNTIeQS2FDk2OQAvOTzVIsbEJvte5Q9x+QA1OQBu4MqZeQA2vMwDAACwg2gAkvxBIsAcDQRC+IIAPJ8Nh6XA0AByEDB+h8PgA5psALq7ZLUOZFC5XFbrbaTH5JJ5rGj+V7ve7kL79IA=

Obviously the x64 optimizer is more aggressive than x86; why that should be, I have no idea (@HansPassant) . I suspect that the optimizer detects that foo is not used after the M1() call and gives its stack location to M1() directly. If you add a method void M2(Foo f) { f = new() ; } and invoke it after M1() as M2(foo);, you will see that now the compiler creates a copy of foo to pass to M1().

WHY?
In .NET, readonly structs ensure immutability, meaning their state cannot change after creation. Even though methods on readonly structs cannot modify their fields (doing so results in a compiler error), defensive copies are created to preserve this immutability contract.
For example:
    readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public int X { get; }
    public MyStruct(int x) => X = x;

    public void ExampleMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Value: {X}");
    }
}

Usage:
readonly MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct(10);
myStruct.ExampleMethod(); // Defensive copy may be created

A defensive copy ensures that the original myStruct is not affected, even though the method doesn’t modify the struct.
When Defensive Copies Occur:

Readonly Fields: Accessing methods or properties on a readonly struct field triggers a copy:
private readonly MyStruct _myStruct;
_myStruct.ExampleMethod(); // Creates a defensive copy

Readonly Parameters: Passing a readonly struct as an in parameter can also result in copies:
void ExampleMethod(in MyStruct myStruct)
{
myStruct.ExampleMethod(); // Creates a defensive copy
}


Why are Copies Needed?
Defensive copies ensure immutability is preserved even if a method could theoretically modify state (although such modification is blocked by the compiler).
Learn more in the Microsoft Docs on readonly structs.

MutatingMethod cannot change the structure. It's not possible. If you try to change it you will end up with compiler error.

Oops yes, a readonly struct guarantees immutability, so any method that tries to modify fields or properties of the struct will fail at compile time.
However, defensive copies are still relevant when a method is invoked on a readonly struct because:
Methods in a readonly struct can still read fields or call other methods, and these operations may not modify state but still require a copy to respect readonly semantics.
The compiler needs to ensure that even indirect modifications (e.g., through mutating an object or array field within the struct) are prohibited.

Defensive copies for readonly structs exist not because the struct itself is mutable, but because the compiler needs to preserve the semantics of readonly.
