Assembly is different for passing structs depending on the size of the struct
I was doing some exploring around defensive copying of structs, and am trying to understand why the instructions change when passing structs of different size to a function with the in keyword.
I have this code sample:
public readonly struct Foo1
{ 
    public readonly int i1;
}
public readonly struct Foo2
{ 
    public readonly int i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6; 
    
}
public class C {
    public static int M(Foo1 foo) {
        var a = M2(foo);
        return a + 1;
    } 
    
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static int M2(in Foo1 f) =>f.i1 + 1;
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static int M2(in Foo2 f) =>f.i1 + 1;    
}

If i change M(Foo1 foo) to M(Foo2 foo) I get different instructions when the only difference is the size of the struct:
C.M(Foo1) :: small struct

L0000: push eax
L0001: mov [esp], ecx
L0004: lea ecx, [esp]
L0007: call 0x376b0018
L000c: inc eax
L000d: pop ecx
L000e: ret


C.M(Foo2) :: large struct

L0000: lea ecx, [esp+4]
L0004: call 0x376f0018
L0009: inc eax
L000a: ret 0x18


Is Foo1 being passed by value here resulting in a defensive copy?
You can see the code here DEMO
Interestingly, if I remove in for the function passing Foo1 you get less instructions to when passing Foo2 with in:
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static int M2(Foo1 f) =>f.i1 + 1; //`in` removed

C.M(Foo1) :: in removed

L0000: call 0x38740018
L0005: inc eax
L0006: ret


I am struggling to understand why there are differences if passing with the in keyword. Shouldn't it be a reference to the struct in both cases not passed by value, so why does the size of the structs change the instructions?

How do you check out the assembly code, sharplab link gives me the similar output for both (img)

Did you change the code for M() because your image only shows M(Foo1) not M(Foo2), you need to edit code so M() accepts Foo2 not Foo1, when you change it, you should see the assembly change for C.M.

Sorry, misunderstood the question then, thought it was for M2's (since there was not added second variant for M)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79193602/why-net-generates-defensive-copies-for-readonly-structs-in-jitted-methods

@HansPassant that doesn't answer the question. Although is similar. I know why defensive copies occur. I was asking about why the assembly is different for different sizes of structs.


Shouldn't it be a reference to the struct in both cases not passed by
value, so why does the size of the structs change the instructions?

Yes. A reference to the struct.
When the struct has a single 32bit field, the compiler passes it via ecx to M, not on the stack.
So when M2 expects a reference/address it can dereference,
C.M2(Foo1 ByRef)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov eax, [ecx] -> HERE ecx should hold an address
    L0005: inc eax
    L0006: pop ebp
    L0007: ret

M is somewhat forced to save its own struct argument value it got on ecx to its stack and pass that stack's address to M2 (no other address is available to pass) - so more of a "referenceable" copy than a defensive copy.
L0000: push eax       // get space on the stack
L0001: mov [esp], ecx // put struct there
L0004: lea ecx, [esp] // get that address in ecx
L0007: call 0x368e0018 // M2(ref struct)

In the larger struct, the struct is already passed by value on the stack for M so it can reuse the address on the stack of its own argument to pass to M2:
L0000: lea ecx, [esp+4]
L0004: call 0x368e0048

